# Double supremum over a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say we have a nonnegative real-valued function $f(a,b)$, and we know that $\sup\limits_{a}(f(a,b))$ is finite for each fixed $b \in (0,1)$, and that $\sup\limits_{b}(f(a,b))$ is also finite for each fixed $a$ in the unit disc in $\Bbb C$.

Can we conclude that $\sup\limits_{b}\sup\limits_{a}(f(a,b))$ (or vice versa) is finite?

If you need more information about regarding $f$, I will give it, but this is the main question I'd like answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general. Take $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{a+b}$, for, let's say, $a,b \in (0,1)$.
Then $\sup_a f(a,b) = \frac{1}{b}$ and $\sup_b f(a,b)=\frac{1}{a}$, but $\sup_a\sup_b f(a,b)=+\infty$.

For your particular choices of domains this doesn't provide a counterexample because your $a$ is allowed to be $0$, but maybe this is still helpful for your purposes.

**Edit:** a counterexample for your specific choice of domains modeled from the example above.
Take $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{\operatorname{Re}(a) + b + 1}$. In this case we have $\sup_a f(a,b) = \frac{1}{b}$ and $\sup_b f(a,b)=\frac{1}{\operatorname{Re}(a) + 1}$ but still $\sup_a\sup_b f(a,b)=+\infty$.

Comment: Good answer, but your comment about $a$ being able to take the value $0$ is actually relevant to the specific problem, now that I ponder it. Is there perhaps a different counterexample relevant to my exact specifications for the sets of allowable $a$s and $b$s? Additionally, your functions are not nonnegative, I noticed.

Comment: @JohnnyApple see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out that the answer accepted is not correct, that's why provide another example after some years.

Note $b \in (0,1)$, and $|a|\in [0,1]$.

Let $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{1-b+|a|}$.

Then,
$\sup_a f(a,b) = \frac{1}{1-b}$

$\sup_b f(a,b)=\frac{1}{1+|a|}$ and

$\sup\limits_{b}\sup\limits_{a}(f(a,b))= \sup\limits_{b} \left\{\frac{1}{1-b}\right\}=+\infty$, so it is not finite